# EDIT control text overflow

Tags: c++, winapi, scroll, overflow, edit

This is simple. I created an EDIT control like this:

```
HWND MYTEXT= CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", 
                            WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_LEFT|ES_MULTILINE, 
                            20, 120, 150, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

but when I type text inside of it I can't type more text than the width of the EDIT control. When I reach the end it's like there's no more space and I get a beep. How can I make the text scroll in this situation?

Answer (score 4):

You can give your edit control the `WS_HSCROLL` and/or `WS_VSCROLL` [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx). For instance:

```
HWND myText
    = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", 
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE, 
                     20, 120, 150, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

Alternately, as Matthew T. Staebler rightfully suggests, use [ES_AUTOHSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464.aspx#ES_AUTOHSCROLL) and/or [ES_AUTOVSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464.aspx#ES_AUTOVSCROLL) (note the `ES_` prefix, as these are edit styles, not window styles).

Comment: Depending upon the behavior that you want for the scrolling, you may want to consider WS_AUTOHSCROLL and WS_AUTOVSCROLL as alternatives.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.